# Create a dictionary from a two dimensional list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i'm facing some troubles to create a dictionary from a list and a list of lists. Here's an example:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = [[1,2,0], [3,4,1], [5,6,0], [7,8,1]]
```

I want a output using the elements of list ***a*** and the third element of list ***b***, like this output:

```
a = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 1]
```

Both lists have the same length, so i tried something like:

```
c = dict(zip(a,b))
```

But in this case, i can't select the third element of b.

In my real case, i have millions of data, so i need a fast and simple way to do it, and create a temporary list from b may not be a optimal solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
dict(zip(a, (x[-1] for x in b)))  # Maybe x[2] if some of the sublists have more than 3 elements.
```

If you are on python2.x, you might want to use `itertools.izip` or [`future_builtins.zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html)

Answer (score 1):

Or, using a dictionary in comprehension:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = [[1,2,0], [3,4,1], [5,6,0], [7,8,1]]

c = {k: v[-1] for k, v in zip(a, b)}
```

See [PEP274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) Dict Comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this one and it seemed to have worked:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> b = [[1,2,0], [3,4,1], [5,6,0], [7,8,1]]
>>> c = dict(zip(a, [d[2] for d in b]))
>>> c
{'a': 0, 'c': 0, 'b': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `itemgetter` inside the `operator` module. Where **2** represents the index within the *b* sublists.

```
from operator import itemgetter
a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = [[1,2,0], [3,4,1], [5,6,0], [7,8,1]]

c = dict(zip(a, map(itemgetter(2), b)))
```

and since you have lots of elements, maybe `itertools` will help with memory:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import izip, imap

a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = [[1,2,0], [3,4,1], [5,6,0], [7,8,1]]

c = dict(izip(a, imap(itemgetter(2), b)))
```

These solutions will help take advantage of the underlying C modules for performance benefits.